# Why does rotated blurred element get cropped off?

Tags: css, google-chrome

This is the example: https://jsfiddle.net/0w4bcy93/

```css
.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  transform: rotateX(40deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
}

.circle--1 {
  filter: blur(10px) opacity(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="circle circle--1"></div>

<div class="circle circle--2"></div>
```

Both has the same styling except `.circle--1` has filter blur. Is this a browser issue?

edit: You can also try increasing the rotateX and the cropped area will be bigger

edit2: I logged a bug in Chromium https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1108298

Comment: it seems to be a chrome bug (works fine on firefox)

Comment: @TemaniAfif ah, I only tested this with brave and chrome. I will log a bug with chrome then. thanks!

Comment: It's interesting that the crop-line seems to move relative to scroll position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of it's a chrome bug itself. There's a cheat way to work around. By using a parent
filter layer to blur.

```css
.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  transform: rotateX(75deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
}
.blur-filter {
  filter: blur(10px);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.circle--1 {
  filter: opacity(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="blur-filter">
  <div class="circle circle--1"></div>
</div>

<div class="circle circle--2"></div>
```